# how to reduce latency ngix rtmp server?

Tags: rtmp, latency

I would like to create a rtmp server with minimal latency.

I'm using nginx with ngix with the following configuration file

```
rtmp {
  server {
    listen 1935;
    ping 30s;
    # chunk_size 4096;
    # chunk_size 8192;
    buflen 100ms;
    publish_time_fix off;

    application vod {
        play /usr/local/nginx/rtmp;
    }

    application live {
        live on;
        record off;
        exec ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/drone -threads 1 -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset:v faster -tune zerolatency -an -b:v 300K -f flv -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -b:a 56k rtmp://localhost/live360p/drone;
    }

    application live360p {
        live on;
        record off;
    }

  }
}
```

In Playback I'm using

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/drone -loglevel verbose
```

I'm not sticking with anything except Linux and the video source that is streaming rtmp. So, replace ngix, decrease quality, change playback format are all fine. The most important thing is to reduce latency?

Best Regards

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Your explanation is really good. but you missed the question?